# CSS3 flex - stretches the image instead of centering it?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why does flex center stretch my image instead of centering it?

css:

```
.flex-centre {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      text-align: center;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="height: 400px; width: 400px; background: #ccc">
    <div class="flex-centre">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Any ideas?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfpa4f2o/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have set `flex-direction: column` and now main axis is **Y** and cross axis is X. So because `align-items` distribute items along cross-axis (and default value of `align-items` is `stretch`) now you want to use `align-items: center` to position your image horizontally and prevent image to stretch.

```css
.flex-centre {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 400px; width: 400px; background: #ccc">
  <div class="flex-centre">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Another option is to set left and right `margin` of image to `auto`

```css
.flex-centre {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 400px; width: 400px; background: #ccc">
  <div class="flex-centre">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```