# Bootstrap 3.3.7 - grid system does not work on Safari 10?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, safari, grid, zurb-foundation, grid-system

From the doc [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support) it says that it supports Safari on IOS and Mac desktop.

But why is this what I get on my Safari?

[image]

This is my code:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .grid-item {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 5px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        height:100%;
    }

    .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }

    /* Equal image height */
    /* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157249/css3-flex-stretches-the-image-instead-of-centering-it */
    /* Only apply to large, medium and small screens */
    /* https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries */
    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px),
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
        .eq-height {
          display: -webkit-box;
          display: -webkit-flex;
          display: -ms-flexbox;
          display:         flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
    }

    .eq-height > [class*='col-'] {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .eq-height > [class*='col-'] > [class*='col-'] {
        height:100%;
    }

    /* Hide actual image but use inline cover image */
    a.grid-item img {
        opacity:0
    }

    a.grid-item {
        background-size:cover
    }

    /* Gaps between items/ tiles */
    .col-sm-3 .col-sm-12,
    .col-sm-6 .col-sm-12,
    .col-sm-3 .col-sm-12 + .col-sm-12 {
        margin-top:10px;
    }

    /* Change container size */
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1400px;
        min-width: 320px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1420px) {
        .container {
            padding: 0 20px;
        }
    }

</style>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row eq-height">

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x1200')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x1240" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x603" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row eq-height">

         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x900')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/g/800/1200" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <a href="#" class="grid-item">
                    <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay muted controls loop class="clip-polygon">
                        <source src="big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm">
                    </video>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row eq-height">

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/600x1000')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x1200" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I have looked around but can't find any fix yet. Any ideas?

It is even worst if I upgrade it to [version 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) - it breaks horridly on Chrome!

What about [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) - does it have a better grid system support for all browsers?

Note that you got to run my code on **full page** to see the **correct** grid layout on Chrome, Opera and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Zurb 6 supports the last two versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Mobile Safari, IE Mobile (older Windows Phone and Windows CE devices), IE 9+, and the Android web browser 2.3+

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/compatibility.html

It would be unfair of me to point you to Zurb over Bootstrap.  It is up to you to decide which browsers you need to support.  I'll be happy to help you with specific Zurb questions or issues.

Comment: Thanks. How would you turn that Bootstrap grid above into Foundation? I am new to Foundation. Been on Bootstrap for ages and it's quite frustrating at times!

Comment: I just can't understand why that simple grid layout would fail on Safari!